# Why object is null though i have called the setter from my test code

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, setter, getter

I have below code in my test method

```
VirtualServer virtualServer = new VirtualServer();
virtualServer.initializeServlet();
virtualServer.setServeletObserver(new ANFlipNotAllowedFlagObserver());
.....
.....
```

above 2 lines indicated as .... triggers dev code so that it hits my virtual server.

Virtual server class has below code :-

```
 public class VirtualServer extends HttpServlet
 {
    private volatile Observer observer;

    public synchronized Observer getServeletObserver ()
    {
       return observer;
    }

    public synchronized void setServeletObserver (Observer observer)
    {
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        this.getServeletObserver().subject.setRequestResponse(request, response);
    }
```

When i put a breakpoint just after calling setServeletObserver and inspect the value of virtualserver.getServeletObserver i see the value i have set using my setting. If i set a breakpoint in my virtualServer class in dopost method (after calling the setting from testcode) i see the value of observer object as null. I am not sure why its null. My testclass already called  the setter method on this class. So it shouldnt be null. Can you please help me to findout whats wrong. I used volatile keyword for Observer object. But it didnt help.

Comment: Objects aren't null. *References* are null.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same instance of the object? Another object could be created somewhere else in your code. Also, someone could call `setServeletObserver(null);` since you have no argument check.

Comment: Are you sure that `doPost` is called after `setServeletObserver` ? `doPost` is not synchronized itself

Comment: You could try setting the observer to some default that is not null when creating the VirtualServer object. Or making a log when setting the observer. As @Thomas said, you are probably using another object or modifying the one you think you use somewhere on the way.